# Joomla 2.5: showing category description above Article list

Tags: joomla, module, joomla2.5, categories

i'm searching for a module like the "Articles Categories" module which shows a list of all subcategories of one category. Usually when one category is chosen the list of articles in this category is shown. How can i make that the description of the chosen category is shown above of the article list?

bye!

PS: im using Joomla 2.5.14

Comment: If the existing configuration options don't provide the flexibility that you need, you can create a template override or a layout override for that module or component view.

Comment: yes but i wanted to know if there is any existing module that already does what i want

Comment: I don't know about that, but if the existing module does *exactly* what you want, except for one minor and easily fixable thing, changing it would probably be a more useful experience.